# Find the stationary point and its nature.

Tags: stationary-point

[image]

To find the stationary point I have to find dy/dx=0

so far I reached until this point where I'm not sure how to get the 2 X values:

dy/dx= [image] how to find the stationary points from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-e^{-x}(x^2+x-2)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-e^{-x}(x+2)(x-1)$

Stationary points x=-2 and x=1

L min at x=-2 and L. max at x=1 (first derivative test)
[image: Check for sign change]